# How to add a custom search engine to Chrome when the search is via Javascript, not through the omnibox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I frequently use the Chrome feature of [custom search engines.](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95426?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) For example: I use `so` as a shortcut to StackOverflow; `pd` for the Pandas doc, `py` for the Python doc, etc.

However, I can't do that with [the Xpress documentation](https://www.fico.com/fico-xpress-optimization/docs/latest/overview.html), which I use frequently, since the search happens fully within the Javascript on the page, and the Omnibox does not change.

Is there a way to either write a local file wrapper containing the right html+js, or access that form element via the http call, or add an extension, so that I can create a short cut?